# How to preview Html in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jQuery. I want to preview the html after click on anchor tag. I have one big `textarea` where user will add `html` and `css` on to it.

Like this:

```
<textarea type="text" rows='20' id="FetchHTML" name="html" style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 12pt;"></textarea>

<center><a class="btn btn-danger" id="PreviewHTML" href="javascript:;">Preview</a></center>
```

This is my modal:

```
<!-- Preview Html Template -->
<div class="modal fade" id="PreviewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Preview HTML</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="AppendPreview">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#PreviewHTML',function(){
         var html = $('#FetchHTML').val();
         alert(html);
         $('#AppendPreview').append(html);
         $('#PreviewModal').modal('show');
    })
})
</script>
```

Now user enters the `html` in `textarea`  there is button at bottom preview. 
I entered below `html` in `textarea` :-

[image: image01]

Now when I click on preview button its showing below output

[image: IMAGE02]

In preview 1st not picking the `css` . Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you mean by *"not picking the css"*. Also provide a *runnable* [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Changing

`$('#AppendPreview').append(html);`

to

`$('#AppendPreview').html(html);`

Appears to fix your issue. Run the code snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#PreviewHTML',function(){
         var html = $('#FetchHTML').val();
         
         $('#AppendPreview').html(html);
         $('#PreviewModal').modal('show');
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<textarea type="text" rows='20' id="FetchHTML" name="html" style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 12pt;"></textarea>

<center><a class="btn btn-danger" id="PreviewHTML" href="javascript:;">Preview</a></center>
<!-- Preview Html Template -->
<div class="modal fade" id="PreviewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Preview HTML</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="AppendPreview">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```